# can't compile wine on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I have been trying to compile wine on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and I can't for the life of me figure out what package dependency I'm missing here.  I followed along with the [guide](http://wiki.winehq.org/BuildingBiarchWineOnUbuntu) on winehq and was able to complete it fine... however now I'm trying to compile a [patched](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2013-September/101106.html) version of wine so I can run starcraft 2 with better performance.  When I run ./configure i get the following error

```
checking for freetype/freetype.h... no
checking for freetype/ftglyph.h... no
checking for freetype/fttypes.h... no
checking for freetype/tttables.h... no
checking for freetype/ftsnames.h... no
checking for freetype/ttnameid.h... no
checking for freetype/ftoutln.h... no
checking for freetype/ftwinfnt.h... no
checking for freetype/ftmodapi.h... no
checking for freetype/ftlcdfil.h... no
checking for FT_TrueTypeEngineType... no
configure: error: FreeType 32-bit development files not found. Fonts will not be built.
Use the --without-freetype option if you really want this.
```

I've tried installing `libfreetype6-dev:i386` and `libfreetype6:i386` and many other variations but always get the same error message after `./configure` . any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure libfreetype6-dev:i386 is installing successfully?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`libfreetype6-dev` ***is*** the package that I needed.  The issue is that this package installs the header files needed for the compilation in `/usr/include/freetype2` but the `configure` script is looking for the headers in `/usr/include/freetype` .  So the solution I found was to add a symbolic link in `/usr/include` that points to `/usr/include/freetype2` that is called `freetype`.  This can be done in the terminal like this.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype
```

Comment: were you able to install the `libfreetype6-dev:i386` package?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev` is needed

Comment: nice catch @JaredChu, that works only after I installed both libs

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build wine64 for a Ubuntu Liunx AMI/Docker container, and I was getting this error. I found that I needed to install pkgconfig

```
sudo apt install -y pkgconf
```

Wine uses pkgconf to search for the Freetype library directories, and so couldn't find Freetype without it.

Of course you need the freetype development libraries installed as well

```
sudo apt install -y libfreetype-dev
```